# Facebook like button count not updating at all

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-like

I'm having a problem with the good ol' facebook like button on my site. I've implemented it all, I can click on "like" and it appears on my wall (and on the site the count pops up to say "1"), but the count never updates. If I refresh the page it just shows the "like" button again (no count), and if I log in to facebook with a new account and click on like again, it just says "1" again.

An example page on my site:

> http://www.makemeacocktail.com/recipe/6741/

The fql readout (watch the apostrophe escape here, copy and paste dont just click):

> https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20total_count,like_count,comment_count,share_count,click_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='http://www.makemeacocktail.com/recipe/6741/'&format=json

The FB XML that is being used:

```
    <fb:like href="http://www.makemeacocktail.com/recipe/6741/" send="false" layout="button_count" width="50" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

Other facebook thoughts etc:

I've got the facebook open graph meta data in the head

The js call to facebook happens as the last thing on my page, after the FBML:

```
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=187430904631019&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
    <script>
    FB.init({
    appId  : '187430904631019',
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    xfbml  : true
    });
    </script>
```

I've also got the facebook page like at the bottom of my page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/makemeacocktail" width="292" show_faces="false" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```

Which is where the fb-root is.

My only thought it something about fb-root not being next to the facebook like button earlier up, and a conflict of two facebook like buttons or something? I;m only calling the facebook js once though, right at the bottom.

Any thoughts help etc much appreciated. It is weird because it it going to my wall, but the button on the site isn't listening!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Got this from the request your like button sends to facebook:

> ```
> App ID does not match domain","full":"The app ID specified
> ```
>
> within the \"fb:app_id\" meta tag is
>   not allowed on this domain. You must
>   setup the Connect Base Domains for
>   your app to be a prefix of 
>   http:\/\/www.makemeacocktail.com\/recipe\/6741\/

So, you need to change the base domain for your application in the developers application to makemeacocktail.com. If that is not the problem try removing the fb:app_id open graph tag, or use the fb:admins tag instead. Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Danny. Yeah of course, I had setup an app for the login mechanism but that base domain was something else, and forgot the knock on effects for the like button.

Just a quick question - how do you see the request back from facebook so I can explore further? (ie what you got about App ID not matching)?

Comment: Well, I use the Firebug console, but any other would do. It's just a normal ajax POST request.

Comment: Yeah got it, but now I'm finding this error:
You must specify a URL as part of this widget or API
?
Any thoughts here?